# Detect when my activity has been touched

Tags: android, android-activity, touch

I would like to do a simple thing but I haven't succeeded so far : I would like to know when the user touched anywhere in the activity.

The thing is that when I do `getContentView().setOnTouchListener(...);`, the touch event gets consumed by the child views, and it will only be fired if I touch outside of any view in my activity.

Is there a solution which doesn't involve extending the content view class ?

Thanks !

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/16233887/5552022

Comment: Take a look at http://jhshi.me/2014/11/09/monitor-screen-touch-event-in-android/

Comment: Why not override `onDispatchTouchEvent()` of your `Activity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override

```
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
```

method in activity

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
   boolean touched = false;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    touched=true;
    Log.e("Toched ","Anywhere");

    return touched;
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this ? The `onTouch` method doesn't exist in `Activity`

Comment: you have to apply touch listener to root layout.after that you can override this method.

Comment: This doesn't work as stated in my OP, the child views take over the event of the root layout